# How can I change the spacing of a document throughout?

Tags: spacing

I want one page of my document to be single spaced, and one to be double spaced. I'm using `\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}`, but can't seem to change the spacing throughout.

Comment: Can you edit in your TeX code for the document whose spacing you want to adjust? That might make it clearer what the problem is.
Also, you might have some luck with the `setspace` package, as described [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Paragraph_Formatting#Line_spacing).

Comment: Do you want to alternate single spacing and double spacing for all pages, like ABABABAB or for a single instance?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want the spacing for some text, you could set the spacing in a group, as in inside `curlybraces` `{}`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
{
\baselineskip=1.5\baselineskip
\lipsum[2]
}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's a possibility to use `\usepackage{setspace}` and `\singlespacing` or `\doublespacing` -- insert those commands either in a group or switch back to default `\singlespacing` at the right position (i.e. at a manual pagebreak, if needed).

The advantage of `setspace` is that it will scale the spacing according to the chosen fontsize.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\begin{document}
\marginpar{Single spacing}\singlespacing
\blindtext

\marginpar{One half}\onehalfspacing
\blindtext

\marginpar{Double spacing}\doublespacing
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]